# How to notify a widget about changes in another widget in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt4

I am trying to implement a widget in Qt that has 2 child widgets of its own: one is a *render area* where I draw some points and connect lines between them and the other one is a ListBox where I would like to insert the list of all the points I drew with their coordinates from the render area. The 2 widgets where added with Qt Designer. Here is my code until now:

*renderarea.h:*

```
class RenderArea : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    RenderArea(QWidget *parent = 0);
    QPoint point;
    QList<QPoint> list;

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *);
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
    void updateList(QPoint p);
};
```

*renderarea.cpp:*

```
RenderArea::RenderArea(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Base);
    setAutoFillBackground(true);
}

void RenderArea::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    point = e->pos();
    updateList(point);
    this->update();
}

void RenderArea::updateList(QPoint p)
{
    list.append(p);
}
void RenderArea::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * /* event */)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black,2));
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
        painter.drawPoint(list[i]);
    if (list.size()>1)
        for(int j = 0; j < list.size()-1; ++j)
                painter.drawLine(list[j], list[j+1]);
}
```

*paintwidget.h:*

```
class PaintWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit PaintWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~PaintWidget();

private:
    Ui::PaintWidget *ui;
};
```

*paintwidget.cpp:*

```
PaintWidget::PaintWidget(QWidget *parent) :
        QWidget(parent),
        ui(new Ui::PaintWidget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

PaintWidget::~PaintWidget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

My question is how to transmit from the render area widget to my ListBox that I drew another point and it should be displayed along with its coordinates in the list?

Comment: Why use `new` and `delete` instead of just containing a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OrcunC gave you a good advice.
If your are new to signal/slots implementation here some hints you can start from.

*renderarea.h*

```
signal:
    void pointAdded(QPoint*);
```

*renderarea.cpp*

```
void RenderArea::updateList(QPoint p)
{
    list.append(p);
    emit pointAdded(&list.back());
}
```

*listbox.h*

```
public slots:
    void onPointAdded(QPoint*);
```

*listbox.cpp*

```
void ListBox::onPointAdded(QPoint* point)
{
    //lets assume your ListBox is a QListWidget
    addItem( QString::number(point->x()) + "," + QString::number(point->y()))
}
```

*somewhere instance of ListBox and RenderArea are accessible*

```
QObject::connect( renderArea, SIGNAL(pointAdded(QPoint*),
                  listBox,    SLOT(onPointAdded(QPoint*)));
```

NOTE: nameing is very important for readability and maintenance the `void RenderArea::updateList(QPoint p)` in this case it's more `void RenderArea::addPoint( const QPoint& p)` (also notice the `const reference` telling the compiler that we are not changing `p` event if we have it's reference)

Comment: Hi, I tried your code but it is still not working. It just says 

Object::connect: No such slot QListWidget::onPointAdded(QPoint*) in ..\paintWidget\paintwidget.cpp:13

Object::connect:  (sender name:   'displayWidget')

Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'listWidget')

It just doesn't find the slot.

Comment: `QListWidget::onPointAdded(QPoint*)` does not exist directly in Qt. You **must implement your own class** on top of `QListWidget` like `class ListBox : public QListWidget` see some example in Qt for that. Then in **your** `ListBox` define & implement your slot then connect it.

Answer (score 4):

The general approach used in QT development is using [signal/slots](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/signalsandslots.html) for communication between components of software. So basically you need to define a signal in your source component (for instance RenderArea or whereever your like) and connect your slot defined in another component somewhere (i.e your Form Window) and fire a signal upon an action.

There are examples in the referenced link too.